# New to Java - Custom EventHandlers

Tags: java

In this sample(it's from the [Oracle Site](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html)) :

```
// Notify all listeners that have registered interest for
// notification on this event type.  The event instance 
// is lazily created using the parameters passed into 
// the fire method.

protected void fireFooXXX() {
 // Guaranteed to return a non-null array
 Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
 // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
 // those that are interested in this event
 for (int i = listeners.length-2; i>=0; i-=2) {
     if (listeners[i]==FooListener.class) {
         // Lazily create the event:
         if (fooEvent == null)
             fooEvent = new FooEvent(this);
         ((FooListener)listeners[i+1]).fooXXX(fooEvent);
     }
 }
}
```

What does this

> listeners[i]==FooListener.class

Comparison do? It throws me off a bit, since it seems its comparing an instance of a class to a type of class. I would could understand it if it said something like

> listeners[i].getClass() == Foolistener.class

But it doesn't...Can someone enlighten me here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's what the documentation of getListenerList() says it does.

> **public Object[] getListenerList()**
>
> Passes back the event listener list as
> an array of ListenerType-listener
> pairs. Note that for performance
> reasons, this implementation passes
> back the actual data structure in
> which the listener data is stored
> internally! This method is guaranteed
> to pass back a non-null array, so that
> no null-checking is required in fire
> methods. A zero-length array of Object
> should be returned if there are
> currently no listeners. WARNING!!!
> Absolutely NO modification of the data
> contained in this array should be made
> -- if any such manipulation is necessary, it should be done on a copy
> of the array returned rather than the
> array itself.

The array is in pairs of Type and Instance.  So index zero is the class (or superclass) of the actual listener found at index 1, index 2 is the class of the actual listener at 3, etc.

Comment: Right, so it's comparing a type(in the array) to class...make's sense.
So if I used the odd numbers in the array and used listeners[i].getClass() ==FooListener.class it would do the same?

Comment: Not necessarily.  When they're added you specify the type of listener that they will be 'counted' as.  The concrete type of the object at index 1 may actually be a subclass of the class at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like their array alternates between `Class` objects and `FooListener` objects.

For any `n`, `listeners[2n]` will contain a `Class` instance, and `listeners[2n + 1]` will contain a `FooListener` instance for that class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go the complete side-route and suggest **not using `EventListenerList`**.  It's a terrible bit of code that is only useful if you are either in java 1.4 or earlier or you are using one list to hold listeners for several different listener classes.

I'd recommend instead using a `List<FooListener>` for your listener holder.  You can still do the same stuff that `EventListenerList` allows, but your code will be easier to follow.

```
private final List<FooListener> myFooListeners;
...
void fireXXX() {
  FooEvent event = ....
  for (FooListener fl : myFooListeners) {
    fl.xxx(event);
  }
}
```